# Insert new item to all the document of the collection to nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document like

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f26s"),
"group" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f27f"),
"referrers" : [
    {
        "referrer_id" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f20c")
    },
    {
        "referrer_id" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f20d")
    },
    {
        "referrer_id" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f20e")
    }
]
```

Now i need to update one new item {`"canAddUse" : true`} to referrers nested array in all the documents. The output should be like:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f26s"),
"group" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f27f"),
"referrers" : [
    {
        "referrer_id" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f20c"),
        "canAddUser" : true
    },
    {
        "referrer_id" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f20d"),
        "canAddUser" : true
    },
    {
        "referrer_id" : ObjectId("5b0cf3b77f8b9a0a1330f20e"),
        "canAddUser" : true
    }
]
```

How should i run the query to update this in multiple documents at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$[] positional all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/index.html) operator (MongoDB 3.6+) to update all elements in an array and `multi: true` to update all documents.

```
db.col.update({}, { $set: { "referrers.$[].canAddUser": true } }, { multi: true })
```

For lower MongoDB versions you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to overwrite existing field and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to overwrite existing collection:

```
db.colname.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            referrers: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$referrers",
                    as: "r",
                    in: { referrer_id: "$$r.referrer_id", canAddUser: true }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "colname"
    }
])
```

Comment: How to find the position? Can u please explain me for the above example?

Comment: Sorry i got the result as i expected :-) Thanq soo much